# MATLAB | Image Search | SIFT | HASH

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hash, sift, surf

I was trying to implement this paper, **http://www.yugangjiang.info/publication/TMM_queryadaptivesearch.pdf** in MATLAB and I have very basic knowledge of MATLAB.

What I need to do is **extract features from images(SIFT), create a Hash, store it in the database and search different images if any are similar by calculating hamming distance of Hash codes**.

I have tried many MATLAB implementations of SIFT that are available in the internet. But couldn't understand how to apply a Hash to SIFT features and what Hash algorithm to use!

**What hashing algorithm to use here? 
How could I create hash from SIFT features? 
Will it be possible to do the same with SURF features?** 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can create Hash by using SURF features also. If you want to find similar images from database, Apply output of SIFT or SURF features to the hamming distance method or nearest neighbour algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your response. **Could you please tell me which Hash algorithm to use here?** To find hamming distance, **small change in input should result in small change on hash**, right?

Comment: You can use Nearest neighbor algorithm. Small change in input leads to major change in output.